# Is L infinity compactly embedded in L2?

Tags: real-analysis

When the measure space has finite measure is this true? I could take an equibounded sequence in L infinity, thus for almost every point i'd get a bounded sequence in the complex plane, build this way an almost every where limit and thus the L2 convergence by the dominated convergence theorem. Thanks.

Comment: Your Question would likely benefit from [mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for example the unit interval endowed with Lebesgue measure and $f_n\colon x\mapsto \sin(n\pi x) $. Then $\left\lVert f_n\right\rVert_\infty\leqslant 1$ and if a subsequence converges in $\mathbb L^2$ to some $f$, then $f=0$ (because $f_n\to 0$ weakly) but a subsequence cannot converge to $0$ in the $\mathbb L^2$-norm.

Comment: Right thanks, the point is then that I am taking an uncountable union to build the almost everywhere limit, therefore the resulting union could have a positive measure?